# Issues with Extracting Tables from bank transaction PDFs

Tags: python, dataframe, pdf, extract, ocr

I am working on a python code for extracting tables from bank transactional pdfs(not image based pdfs).

currently have worked with extracting tabular data using Tabula and Camelot but these are not robust enough

with 2 main issues I am working on.

1. Column Data Misplacement:

   Occasionally, the data within columns, particularly timestamp, narration, and counterparty, are inaccurately positioned. This results in misalignment of data where values from one column are erroneously placed into another. For example, the timestamp values may be incorrectly transposed into the narration column, leading to data displacement and inconsistency.
2. Column Splitting:

   Another observed issue involves the splitting of text data from the narration and counterparty columns into adjacent columns. This fragmentation disrupts the structure of the extracted tables and poses challenges during data processing.

Comment: *"This results in misalignment of data where values from one column are erroneously placed into another. For example, the timestamp values may be incorrectly transposed into the narration column, leading to data displacement and inconsistency."* - How does a knowledgeable human recognize such issues? After all, a human also sees the data in the wrong fields... I'd imagine a knowledgeable human on one hand recognizes the format of the timestamp in your example and would expect it in some other field. Furthermore, a knowledgeable human knows certain patterns of such filled-in forms. ...

Comment: ... Thus, that's what you also can try to do, analyze the type of the data in each field, and if the type is not typical for that field and a more appropriate field is nearby, assume the content to be from that field. And check whether the data recognized for the form makes sense as filled in, and if it is not, check whether moving a piece of data from one field to another, nearby one makes the data make more sense. Of course, instead of developing such algorithms manually, you can try and train an AI to do that job. Whenever you repair data, though, have a human check.